# Can a CNN be trained to match two different pictures of the same painted rock?

Tags: image, deep-learning, convolution

I am trying to design a convolutional neural network that will match two images together. The images will be of painted rocks. One person will paint the rock, take a picture of it and hide it. Another person will find the rock and take a picture of it. I want to CNN to be able to search s database of images and match the photes to indentify the right rock.

I understand how to train a CNN to classify a photo by giving it many examples and then asking it to match a new picture to the category. I am having trouble figuring out a way to train the CNN to match two images together out of one database. The photos will be slightly different because two people are taking a picture of the same rock at different times.

I can reduce the size of the image search on the database by using GPS locations most times but not always. Meaning the person that hides the rock will hopefully record the location and the person finding will also record the location where they found it.  This way the CNN has to only compare let's say six rocks from around that location to the rock the person found. The rock images will have profiles associated with them to allow for communication between the finder and the hider.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can set this up?

Comment: Hey Jason - the answer is probably *yes*, but as the *answer* would be very broad and open ended, the question might be considered off-topic for StackOverflow.  Please read [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for some background on this: *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*.

Comment: Thanks Alex I get what your saying. To narrow my question I will ask this. What algorithms and libraries would be best suited for this task. Please provide pros and cons if possible. Thanks

Comment: That would also off-topic - please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*.  StackOverflow is sort of for straight-answer, straightforward programming questions.  There might be other StackExchange sites that would still be helpful in your particular case.